# Using ArcGIS to assign values from a shapefile to a new field of a second shapefile if they are intersecting

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-pro

I have a polygon feature set (blue) which has the shape of a raster dataset and I have another shapefile (green) where the polygons are seperated by the "borders" of the raster polygon file. What would be the fastest way to assign the values of one column of the green shapefile to a new column in the blue shapefile if they intersect? Also if they do not intersect assigning a value like 9999 would be perfect. So far I got the best result with union but I would like avoid creating a new file and I also don't need every column from the green shapefile.

My files look like this:
[image: two polygon features]

Comment: Try Spatial Join: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm

Comment: Spatial join also creates a new file and I have no real control over the what attribute fields I want to join.

Comment: For some of the blue polygons there are multiple green ones, from which green one do you want to transfer attributes to the blue?

Comment: The value of each green polygon within one blue polygon is the same, it represents a fraction of the blue area and it is actually a multipart polygon so there is just one green polygon within a blue polygon

Comment: Near analysis will do. If near distance!=0 they do not intersect.

Comment: Thank you FelixIP that is working so far but there are also a few steps to finally get the needed values in to my target shape. Maybe I try solving this problem with arcpy.